# 2 column values to be one row in seperate columns

Tags: sql

i googled for similar question but it seems to be hard to understand the provided solutions.basically, i wanted to get the values of two column to be next to other,rather than seperate rows for same ERpCusCode.I appreciate  a help or simple example which can be achievable for this question.

Myquery is

```
select distinct gg.* from
(

select cc.*,count (xc.BudgetGroupId )as total ,'' as added from  ---,COUNT (av.BudgetGroupId),COUNT (av.BudgetGroupId)
            (

            select * from (
                    SELECT distinct
                    c.ERpCusCode, c.Name,c.id as CustomerID
                            FROM LoyaltyProgramResult AS lpr 
                    JOIN Customer AS c ON lpr.CustomerId=c.Id 

                    WHERE lpr.InvoiceNo IS NULL AND lpr.[Year]='2018' AND  lpr.[Month]='8'
                    AND lpr.DistributionCenterId=1 AND c.RouteId=33 and lpr.LoyaltyProgramId=71
                    group by 
                    c.ERpCusCode,lpr.AreaSalesManagerId,
                    c.Name,c.id ,lpr.[Year],
                    lpr.[Month],lpr.DistributionCenterId,
                    c.RouteId,lpr.LoyaltyProgramId,
                    lpr.Incentive,lpr.Approve
                    )rowdetails --where  prn=1

            )cc 

left join 

( select bg.*
 from budgetgroupsales  bg
 where customerId=165 and
  qty!=100
 and bg.RouteId =33

 and MONTH(bg.InvoiceDate) = 10
 and YEAR (bg.InvoiceDate) = 2018

 )xc on cc.CustomerID =xc.CustomerId 

 group by cc.ERpCusCode,cc.AreaSalesManagerId, cc.Name,cc.CustomerID ,cc.year,cc.Month ,cc.DistributionCenterId ,cc.routeId,
 cc.LoyaltyProgramId,cc.Incentive,cc.Approve,cc.prn--,total ,added

 union 

 select cc.*,'' as total,count (xc.BudgetGroupId )as added from  ---,COUNT (av.BudgetGroupId),COUNT (av.BudgetGroupId)
        (
        select * from (
                    SELECT distinct

                    c.ERpCusCode, c.Name,c.id as CustomerID

                    FROM LoyaltyProgramResult AS lpr 
                    JOIN Customer AS c ON lpr.CustomerId=c.Id 

                    WHERE lpr.InvoiceNo IS NULL AND lpr.[Year]='2018' AND  lpr.[Month]='8'
                    AND lpr.DistributionCenterId=1 AND c.RouteId=33 and lpr.LoyaltyProgramId=71
                    group by 
                    c.ERpCusCode,lpr.AreaSalesManagerId,
                    c.Name,c.id ,lpr.[Year],
                    lpr.[Month],lpr.DistributionCenterId,
                    c.RouteId,lpr.LoyaltyProgramId,
                    lpr.Incentive,lpr.Approve
                    )rowdetails --where  prn=1

        )cc

left join 

( select bg.*
 from budgetgroupsales  bg
 where customerId=165 and
  qty!=100 and  qty=200
 and bg.RouteId =33

 and MONTH(bg.InvoiceDate) = 10
 and YEAR (bg.InvoiceDate) = 2018

 )xc on cc.CustomerID =xc.CustomerId 

 group by cc.ERpCusCode,cc.AreaSalesManagerId, cc.Name,cc.CustomerID ,cc.year,cc.Month ,cc.DistributionCenterId ,cc.routeId,
 cc.LoyaltyProgramId,cc.Incentive,cc.Approve,cc.prn--,total,added


 )as gg 
 group by ERpCusCode,AreaSalesManagerId,Name,CustomerID,year,Month
 ,DistributionCenterId,routeId,LoyaltyProgramId,Incentive,Approve,total,added,prn
```

current return dataset is

```
  ERpCusCode    Name CustomerID  total  added
ADLAD00001724   y     743          0          0
ADLAD00001774   x     165          0          2
ADLAD00001774   x     165         10          0
```

what I needed

```
 ERpCusCode Name CustomerID  total  added

 ADLAD00001724  y     743          0          0

 ADLAD00001774  x     165         10          2
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

use aggregate function max() and remove distinct put code and name in group by

```
select gg.ERpCusCode ,gg.Name ,max(total) as total ,max(added) from
(

select cc.*,count (xc.BudgetGroupId )as total ,'' as added from  ---,COUNT (av.BudgetGroupId),COUNT (av.BudgetGroupId)
            (

            select * from (
                    SELECT distinct
                    c.ERpCusCode, c.Name,c.id as CustomerID
                            FROM LoyaltyProgramResult AS lpr 
                    JOIN Customer AS c ON lpr.CustomerId=c.Id 

                    WHERE lpr.InvoiceNo IS NULL AND lpr.[Year]='2018' AND  lpr.[Month]='8'
                    AND lpr.DistributionCenterId=1 AND c.RouteId=33 and lpr.LoyaltyProgramId=71
                    group by 
                    c.ERpCusCode,lpr.AreaSalesManagerId,
                    c.Name,c.id ,lpr.[Year],
                    lpr.[Month],lpr.DistributionCenterId,
                    c.RouteId,lpr.LoyaltyProgramId,
                    lpr.Incentive,lpr.Approve
                    )rowdetails --where  prn=1

            )cc 

left join 

( select bg.*
 from budgetgroupsales  bg
 where customerId=165 and
  qty!=100
 and bg.RouteId =33

 and MONTH(bg.InvoiceDate) = 10
 and YEAR (bg.InvoiceDate) = 2018

 )xc on cc.CustomerID =xc.CustomerId 

 group by cc.ERpCusCode,cc.AreaSalesManagerId, cc.Name,cc.CustomerID ,cc.year,cc.Month ,cc.DistributionCenterId ,cc.routeId,
 cc.LoyaltyProgramId,cc.Incentive,cc.Approve,cc.prn--,total ,added

 union 

 select cc.*,'' as total,count (xc.BudgetGroupId )as added from  ---,COUNT (av.BudgetGroupId),COUNT (av.BudgetGroupId)
        (
        select * from (
                    SELECT distinct

                    c.ERpCusCode, c.Name,c.id as CustomerID

                    FROM LoyaltyProgramResult AS lpr 
                    JOIN Customer AS c ON lpr.CustomerId=c.Id 

                    WHERE lpr.InvoiceNo IS NULL AND lpr.[Year]='2018' AND  lpr.[Month]='8'
                    AND lpr.DistributionCenterId=1 AND c.RouteId=33 and lpr.LoyaltyProgramId=71
                    group by 
                    c.ERpCusCode,lpr.AreaSalesManagerId,
                    c.Name,c.id ,lpr.[Year],
                    lpr.[Month],lpr.DistributionCenterId,
                    c.RouteId,lpr.LoyaltyProgramId,
                    lpr.Incentive,lpr.Approve
                    )rowdetails --where  prn=1

        )cc

left join 

( select bg.*
 from budgetgroupsales  bg
 where customerId=165 and
  qty!=100 and  qty=200
 and bg.RouteId =33

 and MONTH(bg.InvoiceDate) = 10
 and YEAR (bg.InvoiceDate) = 2018

 )xc on cc.CustomerID =xc.CustomerId 

 group by cc.ERpCusCode,cc.AreaSalesManagerId, cc.Name,cc.CustomerID ,cc.year,cc.Month ,cc.DistributionCenterId ,cc.routeId,
 cc.LoyaltyProgramId,cc.Incentive,cc.Approve,cc.prn--,total,added


 )as gg 
 group by gg.ERpCusCode ,gg.Name
```

Comment: thank you, it worked like a charm. However ,could you please explain reason for including max() function, to achieve the task

Comment: @Udk max() is aggregate function which work on group of records

Comment: got it, and if the question was clear to you, can you vote it. so that others might find it helpful as well.